# Find out what fields are available to IIS 7 Advanced Logging from Modules

Tags: iis, iis-7, logging

You can install the [Advanced Logging module for IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/advanced-logging). Once installed you have the option to define new fields from several different sources. One of those sources is other modules.

What I am unable to figure out is how to get a list of the fields that the other modules 'publish'. There a boat load of modules installed by default and I have to imagine they are publishing some data I would care to know about (hopefully UrlRoutingModule publishes what I'm specifically looking for).

Also as an aside if you know how to or know where good documentation on writing .net HttpModules that publish custom fields I'd love to see/hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this for a while, I don't think it is actually possible for other IIS Modules to 'publish' fields to be used in Advanced Logging.

I think the 'Source Type' 'Module' refers to the Advanced Logging module itself, not any arbitrary native or managed module.

It may be possible to have your own module adding Request headers into the request which are then picked up as custom fields by the Advanced Logging module.  Your module would have to run before the logging module in the request pipeline.